# exporting data into double array

Tags: java, arrays, database

I want to add retrieved data from database into a array, but its retrieval data null. what is my mistake? Please help me.

```
for (User u : userLists) {
            for (Resource r : resourceLists) {

                String ratingQuery
                        = "SELECT rank FROM ratings WHERE userindex='"
                        + u.getIndex()
                        + "' AND resourceindex='"
                        + r.getIndex()
                        + "'";

                try {
                    ratingCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                    stmt = ratingCon.prepareStatement(ratingQuery);
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                    rate = rs.getDouble("rank");
                    ratings[u.getIndex()][r.getIndex()] = rate; //it seems here is the problem
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! " + e);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in this line, if `ratings` is a 2-dimensional array of double:

```
ratings[u.getIndex()][r.getIndex()] = rate;
```

But may be your database returns empty `ResultSet`? Insert print statement to debug:

```
  while (rs.next()) {
      rate = rs.getDouble("rank");
       System.out.println("Result set is not empty! Current rank is: " + rate);
      ratings[u.getIndex()][r.getIndex()] = rate; //it seems here is the problem
  }
```

If it prints nothing - then the problem not in your code but in db data. Also I think you missed semicolon `;` at the end of your query.

And about exception handling:

```
 catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! " + e);
 }
```

The exception type you catch here is too abstract - you can't know whether it was `SQLException` exception or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Change it to several catch blocks.

Comment: Thank you. every thing is correct except `ratings[u.getIndex()][r.getIndex()] = rate;` line. i defined `double ratings [][] = null;` should i determine its size? how?

Comment: if you know it's exact size (for example 100 100), then: `double ratings [][] = new double [100][100];` . If you don't - use `ArrayList` instead. See fmardini's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.. i knew the exact size.. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java are fixed size

Use an ArrayList and add elements to it

Something like this

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> h = new HashMap<Integer,  ArrayList<Integer>>();
if (!h.containsKey(1)) h.put(1, new ArrayList<Integer>());
h.get(1).add(2);
System.out.println(h.get(1).get(0));
```